# Batch to move files based on total size

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, move

I have 900k files in a particular folder that I need to move daily to another folder based on the total size of 100 mbs. I've tried the following code, but it moves 100 files, not the total amount of 100 mbs

```
@echo on

set Source=C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Dropbox\Pre
set Target=C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Dropbox\Pos

set MaxLimit=10

for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%G in ('dir /A-D /B "%Source%\*.*" ^| find /v /n ""') do (
move /y "%Source%\%%~nxH" "%Target%"
if %%G==%MaxLimit% exit /b 0
)

pause
```

I need the batch to move a selection on files that the sum of their size is less than or equal to 10 kbs. Basically to do the same if I manually selected N files that make up 100 mbs.
I believe that it didn't work because it checks only the single file size.

Comment: Where is the code you have written to perform the task you've laid out in your question? We are not here to write it for you! Our purpose is to assist you in fixing a specific and reproducible issue with your submitted code, and as you've told us that your code works, we have nothing to fix. Your question is therefore an expectation for somebody to write code for you, or to perform a search, and locate a similar answer for you. Unfortunately that is not the purpose of this site, and as you are not a brand new account holder, you should know better. Please read [ask] to refresh your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the post with the code I tried and result

Comment: That really is not good enough! I can see very little chance of you having a file with no extension, named `10` in `C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Dropbox\Pre`. You have made absolutely no attempt at determining any individual file sizes, performing no running total calculations or anything close to what you've requested. We expect that you make a reasonable attempt at the task, and as there have definitely been similar questions and answers on this site using the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, you certainly need to use the search engine at the top of the page, to assist you in that attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you must keep track of how much data has been copied and check to see if it is over MaxLimit. This is not difficult in PowerShell. This script will copy up to $MaxLimit bytes to $TargetDir. This script requires PowerShell Core 6+. The current stable version at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell is 7.1.5. This can be made to work with the old Windows PowerShell 5.1 by changing the Join-Path statements.

Place these two (2) files in the same directory. When you are confident that the correct files will be copied to the correct directory, remove the `-WhatIf` from the Move-Item command.

=== Move-PictureBatch.bat

```
@pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0Move-PictureBatch.ps1"
```

=== Move-PictureBatch.ps1

```
#Requires -Version 6
$MaxLimit = 100MB
$SourceDir = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop' -AdditionalChildPath 'Pre'
$TargetDir = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop' -AdditionalChildPath 'Pos'
$CurrentSize = 0

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $SourceDir |
    ForEach-Object {
        if (($CurrentSize + $_.Length) -lt $MaxLimit) {
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $TargetDir -WhatIf
            $CurrentSize += $_.Length
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
```